# how to show a hidden window in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have two codes:

```
untitled.py
vprs.py
```

When I switch to a new window (vprs.py ) the first one is hiding (untitled.py ).
In the window vprs.py I have a "Back" button, how do I make the first window appear when I click on this button(untitled.py ).

here is the code:

untitled.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from ohelp import Ui_oHelp
from vprs import ui_vprs_ElectroMagnetic, Moshnost_electro

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def openohelp(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_oHelp()
        self.ui.setupUui(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        ***
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.openohelp)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(quit)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.vprsElectro)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.mossh) # Transition function to vprs

    def mossh(self):
        self.windo = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Moshnost_electro()
        self.ui.moshui(self.windo)
        self.windo.show()
        MainWindow.hide()

    def vprsElectro(self):
        self.window1 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = ui_vprs_ElectroMagnetic()
        self.ui.vprsui(self.window1)
        self.window1.show()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        ***
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

vprs.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from electrom_test import Ui_Electrom
from mosh_rabotaem import Ui_Window

class Moshnost_electro(object):
    def moshui(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(338, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 321, 241))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 250, 321, 241))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 502, 321, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 338, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retrans(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.fixx) # button 'back'

    def fixx(self): #function button back
        pass
    
    def retrans(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Варианты задач"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Формулы"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Назад в меню"))
```

I tried to solve the problem myself, but nothing worked. (If you need any more lines of code, I will add it). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could connect the new window's button `clicked` signal with the `show` of the previous one.

Basically, the following *could* be enough:

```
    def mossh(self):
        self.windo = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Moshnost_electro()
        self.ui.moshui(self.windo)
        self.windo.show()
        MainWindow.hide()
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(MainWindow.show)
```

***But***. While that could work, I would strongly discourage it, and that's because there are serious problems with your code that, sooner or later would create other issues.

First of all, pyuic generated files should never, ***ever*** be edited. Those files are intended to be used exclusively as *imports*, and *always* be left unchanged (read more about this *very important* aspect in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)).

Another important problem is that you're constantly overwriting `self.ui`, which is wrong because for two reasons: first of all, every window should have its own reference to the ui, and then every time you do `self.ui = ...` you lose any possible, direct way to access the *current* ui.

So, the first step is to rebuild *all* ui files (each UI will have its own file), including that referring to the main window. Then, that main window will create all other windows in the `__init__` and show them when appropriate (instead of continuously creating them).

In the following example, I'm assuming you've generated the main window ui as `ui_mainWindow.py`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from ui_mainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
from ohelp import Ui_oHelp
from vprs import Moshnost_electro


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.helpWindow = HelpWindow()
        self.mosshWindow = MosshWindow()

        self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.openohelp)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.mossh)

        self.mosshWindow.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.show)

    def openhelp(self):
        self.helpWindow.show()

    def mossh(self):
        self.hide()
        self.mosshWindow.show()


class HelpWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_oHelp):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


class MosshWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Moshnost_electro):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.hide)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Further notes:

- only classes and constants should have capitalized names (as you can see above, I used `mainWindow = MainWindow()`);
- you should also never refer to global variables of instances of objects that could potentially have more than instance (like you did with `MainWindow.hide()`;
- fixed/hardcoded geometries are always discouraged, and [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) should *always* be preferred (even from [Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html));
- instead of QMainWindow, you should consider a [QDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html) for external windows and use `exec()`, and that's also because right now if the user closes the other window, it will not automatically reopen the main one (and the program will exit); note that if you want to switch to dialog, you cannot reuse the same ui file, and you need to create a new one in Designer;